# Проблема с Url в YII2

Tags: php, yii2

Пытаюсь освоить Yii2 и столкнулся с такой проблемой:
с помощью gii генератора создал модуль админки и в `view/layouts/main.php`
в навигации сделал ссылку на модуль вот таким образом:

`['label' => 'Login', 'url' => ['admin/default/index']]`

Проблема следующая  - при переходе по ссылке с представления сайта, то есть из каталога `view`, все работает правильно, но при использовании этой же ссылки из каталога модуля - url выглядит следующим образом:

```
http://yiiblog.loc/admin/admin/default/index
```

а должен быть

```
http://yiiblog.loc/admin/default/index
```

Понимаю что нужно какое то условие написать при обращении из каталога модулей, но не пойму в какую сторону копать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пишите урл со слешем в начале ['/admin/default/index']

> If the route has no leading slash (e.g. site/index), it is considered to be a route relative to the current module and will be prepended with the module's uniqueId.

Comment: Спасибо, мне показалось, что такой вариант я уже пробовал.